# TPM PCRs not reset on TPM reset or on reboot

Tags: tpm

I have a Raspberry Pi with a TPM chip, where I use the TPM for disk encryption. The disk encryption password is sealed to the TPM using PCR register 0. I extend the PCR on the start of the system with certain values, but I found out that PCR 0 only resets on a power cycle, and not on a reboot.

Also running `tpm2_shutdown --clear && tpm2_startup --clear` does not reset the value, while the TPM spec states the following:

> TPM Reset is a Startup(CLEAR) that follows a Shutdown(CLEAR), or a Startup(CLEAR) for which
> there was no preceding Shutdown() (that is, a disorderly shutdown). A TPM Reset is roughly analogous
> to a reboot of a platform. As with a reboot, most values are placed in a default initial state, but persistent
> values are retained. Any value that is not required by this specification to be kept in NV memory is
> reinitialized. In some cases, this means that values are cleared, in others it means that new random
> values are selected.

How can I reset PCR 0 on a reboot?

The TPM is connected by a in-house made PCB, so it could be a hardware-connection problem.

Comment: What is the manufacturer of TPM? Some manufacturers do not allow resetting PCR 0-15 due to been part of SRTM.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I needed the use the physical reset PIN of the TPM-chip. I found the information in the [datasheet](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon-SLB_9670VQ2.0-DataSheet-v01_04-EN-1838547.pdf). The chip I have is the Infineon `SLB9670VQ20FW785XTMA1`.

Table 3 in the datasheet describes that the `RST#` pin is typically
connected to the `PCIRST#` signal of the host. I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is triggered by a reboot.

My Raspberry Pi does not have a `PCIRST#` signal, but had the reset pin connected to pin 19. I solved the issue by executing `gpio 19 out 0` on shutdown. Meaning that GPIO pin 19 is put on low, triggering a reset. Optionally I could set the pin to high on boot, but it works like this.

Comment: Do your security properties rely on the reset being done on shutdown? If so, it should be done in hardware, not software. E.g. keep the `RST#` pin normally low until the CPU pull it up.

Comment: I know that would be better to do it with hardware, but the TPM is placed on a PCB that is connected to a Raspberry Pi Compute Module, and I can't just change the PCB. But if you know a pin on the Compute Module that has about the same functionality as the `PCIRST#` signal, we could use it in a future version.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really a hardware guy, found out that the Compute Module spec does include the `PCIe_nRST` pin.